# Interpolate between 3D plane and 3D hemisphere

Tags: transformation, 3d, interpolation

I have a simple 3D plane whose points (different $x, y$ values, but all $z = 0$) need to be mapped to 3D Cartesian coordinates in order to form a hemisphere. However, I also would like to be able to have a parameter for how much like a plane or how much like a hemisphere the result is, so something like interpolating between a plane and a hemisphere.

I have tried to search up this topic, but I'm a not sure what to call this exactly.

Note that I am ***not*** looking for map projection: I'm *not* looking to map points on the plane to longitude and latitude on the sphere. Rather, **what I'm looking for is** how to transform point $A (x, y, 0)$ on the plane to the point $A' (x', y', z')$ on a 3D object that is a mix between a plane and a hemisphere (defined by $t$; $t = 0$ is the original flat plane, $t = 1$ is a full hemisphere).

For example, this is my original plane (I highlighted one point on the plane to track its position):
[image: Original Plane]
(This should also be the result of interpolation at $t = 0$.)

Expected result at $t = 0.5$:
[image: t = 0.5]

... and at $t = 1$ - complete hemisphere:
[image: Hemisphere]

Note where the highlighted point on the frame is now. I would like to find the 3D Cartesian coordinates of this new point (just going to call it $A'$ again), given the original starting point from the plane $A$ and $t$ to determine how much to interpolate.

Any suggestions/pointers on which equations to use to achieve this interpolation effect?

---

**EDIT:** Here's an animation for the interpolation effect with $t = [0..1]$:
[image]

Comment: So for fixed $t$ is it OK if the map at that point is into some (perhaps large) sphere? [Idea here is to begin with a map from $(x,y,0)$ to a point on a very large diameter hemisphere, then follow that up when $t$ increases so at say $t=1$ you're mapped to a unit sphere.]

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, I think that should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like
$$
A_{t}(x, y) = (1 - t)(x, y, 0) + t\frac{(x, y, -1)}{\sqrt{1 + x^{2} + y^{2}}},
$$
which does a "straight-line homotopy" between the planar embedding $(x, y) \mapsto (x, y, 0)$ and the "radial scaling"
$$
(x, y, -1) \mapsto \frac{(x, y, -1)}{\|(x, y, -1)\|}
  = \frac{(x, y, -1)}{\sqrt{1 + x^{2} + y^{2}}}.
$$

Generally, if $A_{0}$ and $A_{1}$ are mappings with the same domain, and if $\tau$ is a real-valued function of one variable that satisfies $\tau(0) = 0$ and $\tau(1) = 1$, then
$$
A_{t} = \bigl(1 - \tau(t)\bigr)A_{0} + \tau(t) A_{1}
$$
interpolates between $A_{0}$ and $A_{1}$ by moving each point of the image along a line segment. (By taking, say, $\tau(t) = \sin^{2} (\pi t)$, you can "smooth" the start and end of the interpolating animation.)

[image: Interpolating between a plane and a hemisphere]

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer :). However, would it be possible to curve up the corners and make two of them meet as well? For example, with this equation, the corners stay flat until the very end and are at their own ends. However, I was looking for something that slowly [curves up the corners through the interpolation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g221t.png), and [creates "poles" at opposite ends where two of the original corners from the plane meet up](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1xVy5.png).

Comment: Briefly, yes. :) If you have specific parametrizations in mind, such as$$A_{0}(x, y) = (y, x, 0),\qquad A_{1}(x, y) = (-\cos y, \sin x \sin y, -\cos x \sin y),$$for $-\tfrac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \tfrac{\pi}{2}$, $0 \leq y \leq \pi$, you can use the final displayed equation to write down the desired deformation.

Comment: Thanks, this gives the desired results.